# How to get added Statuses on report creation in Jira Service Desk?

Tags: jira

**How to get added Statuses on report creation in Jira Service Desk?**

I added new issue status in Jira Statuses list and i want to access these added statuses list on Report Creation but I'm not able to getting it.

And see following screenshot for more understanding...
[image]

[image]